# Choice of t-test for the following problem

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, t-test

Nine students are selected at random and obtained scores on their verbal and quantitative reasoning tests. We are supposed to test the belief that the students possess the two abilities in different degrees.

This is just a summary of the question. I would like to know if these the two sets of scores are independent or not. Because by my logic, since these tests test different abilities of each student, the scores for each test would be independent of each other. But I'm not so sure.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/top-k-list-of-reasons-to-close-a-question-immediately/3176#3176))

Comment: Also please add `[self-study]` tag and read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: Oh alright. So sorry about that.  I'll correct it.

Answer (score 3):

Since for each student, you have a pair of results (quantitative and verbal test scores),  paired t-test, should be used.

Comment: But quantitative and verbal reasoning tests test different abilities right? So shouldn't they be independent?

Comment: No they shouldn't. Independece refers here to a way you obtained your samples. Sample from quantitative abilities and sample for verbal abilities are obtained from the same group. And you can match each qualitative abilities result with "its own" verbal ablilities result. So they are not independent in above meaning

Comment: Lukasz: Certainly it is technically possible that they are independent! It is unlikely, but it would be hard to justify the claim that any two things measured on the same person must be statistically dependent! (PS I agree with your answer regarding the "Choice of t-test" title of the question, see my answer.)

Comment: I shouldn't have been using word "independent" here. "paired" is better.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer (paired t-tests should be used) is correct if the question is what test should be used to compare the means, however that isn't quite what the thread question asks if I understand it correctly.

Independence is a rather strong assumption, it says "they don't have anything to do with each other". If they come from the same student, they are connected, even though in a certain respect they may be quite different. Technically they may be indeed (approximately) independent, but that's a strong claim to be investigated in its own right, rather than something to be *assumed* when picking a test for testing something else, namely whether they are on average the same. So you'd play it safer not assuming independence, even though there may not be strong dependence between them. I haven't tried to form an opinion based on the data (edit: an earlier version of the question had showed data but this seems to have been edited out in the meantime) whether there is such dependence indeed; you could compute a correlation and test the hypothesis correlation=0, but apart from the fact that correlation=0 isn't equivalent to independence but only one aspect of it, also your test would have a small power detecting dependence because of the small sample size.

A different issue is whether a t-test testing equality of averages, paired or unpaired, is precisely the right thing addressing the question that is asked on the scanned document or whether that is even possible from these data; equality of averages and "students focusing on both abilities to the same degree" (which was the wording on the original scanned document that has now apparently been edited out) isn't really the same thing. (What I write here still applies to the version of the question currently visible to me, if only in sense, not literally... the beauty of responding to questions that are substantially edited while responding...)

Comment: With reference to that last paragraph, the question I received from my teacher was in the context of paired t-tests.

Comment: If you only want to get the question of your teacher right in the sense of your teacher, the straight "paired" answer tells you everything. However if you are curious why this is so, and about the general nature of independence (which isn't a stupid thing to be wondering about at all), you can dig a bit deeper...

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation of the "independence" issue. I'm new to this but I get it now.